# googleapiclient HttpError 403 require permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, credentials, google-api-client

I'm using google api, googleapiclient.discovery and build.instances().list() to extract all instances information under my gcp project. But I'm having permission error.

I can run compute.instances().list() fine on local and compute.instances().list() and by using Application Default Credentials. But the default credentials doesn't work when I publish app to server, and it raise exception:

```py
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
2019-07-17T00:55:56.682326031Z google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials.
```

So I need to set credential explicitly. And I downloaded service account key as "credential.json" and tried to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as following

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= "credential.json"

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
compute.instances().list(project="projectname", zone = "us-west1-a").execute()
```

But I'm getting the permission error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lst_temp.py", line 6, in <module>
    compute.instances().list(project="project-name", zone = "us-west1-a").execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/zones/us-west1-a/instances?alt=json returned "Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/projectname'">
```

Comment: Did I set my credential properly? If not how should I do that? Thanks!

Comment: It seems a permissions issue. Please check in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/ that you assigned the `computed.instances.list` role to your service account